# Looking up values based on unique identifier and date range that is valid

Tags: excel-formula

I'm running into a limitation of vlookup but am not familiar enough with other formulas like array formulas and index to figure this out on my own, hopefully you might be able to help me. I have a reference table with unique object ID codes and data attached to these objects that are only valid for certain dates.

For example, this is my table of reference - there is a unique identifier for each object (ID) that has multiple dates in which the Code, Animal, Color may be valid (based on the start date of each row of data)：
[Reference Table 1](https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/01/02/ReferenceTable1.png)
That is， in this example, for object ID '3', the data row of Code: 1007, Color: Green, Animal: Elephant, is valid from 8/15/2010 to 9/26/2011. On 9/27/2011, the Animal changes to Jaguar from Elephant.

In this other table, I'd like to look up the Code, Animal, Color values based on the unique identifier and the date in which this row is valid. I've manually filled out some of the expected values in the highlighted columns here, but I'm hoping to find a formula that would do this automatically because this file has 10k rows...
[Lookup Table](https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/01/02/LookupTable.png)
As you can see in the first row for the object ID '1', since 1/5/2009 falls between 1/1/2005 and 4/21/2013, the data that is valid for object '1' for the date of 1/5/2009 is the data from 1/1/2005, that is - Code:1002, Color:Red, Animal: Dog.

I know that you can use the IF function to see if a date falls within a range, but I'm not sure how to do that by Object ID, since each of these objects have different date ranges that are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated according to comments:

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$13,MATCH(A2&MAX(IF(($H$2:$H$13<=B2)*($G$2:$G$13=A2),$H$2:$H$13)),$G$2:$G$13&$H$2:$H$13,0),1)
```

Please enter as CSE Formula: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Mister 832! I tried the formula and it returned results, but it looks like the results were not respecting the date that the row was valid in and instead just took the last row that matched the lookup ID? [link] (http://tinypic.com/r/30kr5aa/9) For example, the row highlighted in red should correspond to the data for ID 3 since 5/10/2004, which is for 1007, Purple, Elephant, but it's pulling the data from 4/12/2014 instead. The rest appear to be correct, but also because their dates are the last row of the object. How can this be updated?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this was my formula based on the parameters you provided: =INDEX(C2:C13,MATCH(G7&MAX(IF(A2:A13=G7,B2:B13)),A2:A13&B2:B13,0),1)

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, got sidetracked from this project until recently. Thanks, that worked like a charm! This is so helpful, thank you so much!!!